# Angular.js NuGet vs core reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, when you add the Angular.js NuGet package, it adds a ton of angular javascript files.  I've always just added the direct reference to angular.js (local or via google URL) to my projects and it always works fine.

What's the reason for using the NuGet version of Angular.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **Nuget** it's easier to get all dependences (if they exists) and monitor updates when they comes out and install them.

But in case of **Angular.js** **Nuget** still just copy some js files in your project. So if you don't plan to follow updates and you know all dependences you can just copy your files.